# How to add additional "contact me" information to an apple-id

Tags: ipad, apple-id, facetime

For Christmas, our kids gave us a second iPad (new) to go along with our old first generation iPad. Since I'll be starting a new job in a new city next monday, I want to get it set up so we can face time using the two iPads on one apple ID. My plan is to add her phone number or email address to the "reachable at" information on the applied.apple.com site, and then change the FaceTime settings on each iPad, so that we have different numbers/emails associate with each.

Alas, when I log into appleid.apple.com site and try to add a new number, I take the code they text me, but the system comes back and tells me it can't make the change right now, and that I should try later.

After multiple attempts, it's clear something's not working. Any thoughts on how to add additional emails/phone numbers to an appleid account?

Thanks

mo

Comment: Are you attempting this change from a trusted device or from the new device you just received?  Also,  the message you got is something at the "Apple server level;" you may want to contact Apple support directly.

Answer (score 1):

Try add an Apple ID using these steps:

To add an additional email address, follow these steps:

1. Sign in to your Apple ID account page.
2. Click Edit in the Account section.
3. Under Reachable at, select Add More.
4. Enter your additional email address and we'll send a verification to that address. Enter the verification code and click Verify.

If you didn’t get an email:

> Make sure that you enter an email address that you're not already using as an Apple ID. If you want to delete one of your additional email addresses, click  x next to the address.

If the error keeps showing people who have experienced it:

> They had to transfer me to a Senior Advisor who after listening to my explanation concluded that this had to be forwarded to the Engineering Department and for this he had to create a ticket and do some folllow-up.

Comment: Daniil,  that's exactly what I've been trying to do.  The problem is that when I give it a new phone number or a new email to reach me, in either case I get an error message.  For example, when I try a number, it tells me "The request cannot be processed at this time.  Please try again later."  What does it need from me that I'm not giving it?

Comment: You should contact Apple as people who has this issue have done before